# Build a chat application using google accounts in ios using xmpp or any other framwork

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xmppframework

I m new in ios and i have to make a simple chat app using or fetching gmail accounts in my app.I already saw the mobile.tutsplus tutorial.But he is using his own server ejabbered.But i have to use the gtalk or gmail server.I found that i have to use the XMPP framework for that.
  Please tell me that how to use this XMPP framework or any other if that is better.If u have any sample app using XMPP pleaseshow.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks. But i am using this link and running this project i got the error  (Unable to connect to server. Check xmppStream.hostName).I am not able to understand why it is pinching me.

Comment: And also tell me that will it be able to run on simulator or only on device??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using XMPP is very good and easy approch.By using this you can get Buddy list and presence status of the Buddies.

To use XMPP first you need to add XMPP framework to your project and you need to import some class and need to call some delegate methods.Follow the below Tutorial for integrating the XMPP in your project.

https://github.com/robbiehanson/XMPPFramework